# How do I remember trigonometric angles?

Tags: trigonometry

I am really stuck here,
I need help remembering the trigonometric angles,
Can someone point me to a good place to learn them? 
I often confuse when trying to implement them in my problems

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mnemonics_in_trigonometry

Comment: Easiest way is to solve a lot of exercises with them. And I mean a lot. A lot as in "at least 10 times as much as you solved so far".

Comment: O.O That's alot omg btw @Kenny Lau thanks! :D but I wish I can find a better way to learn them 3=

Comment: I've solved "a lot" of trig problems and I can never remember such things.  Usually I wind up drawing the relevant triangle and recalculating everything from scratch with the pythagorean theorem etc. Anything that isn't 30/45/60 that I can't just look up would turn into a bit of a hassle probably.

Comment: Note sure if helpful, but it is interesting https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jy%C4%81,_koti-jy%C4%81_and_utkrama-jy%C4%81

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to understand how to obtain them. I have been studying math for 30 years and I still do this. First $45^{\circ}$ take a right angled triangle with sides $a=b=1$ then by Pythagoras $c^2=1^1+1^1=2$ so $c=\sqrt{2}$ Now you can read off $\cos 45^{\circ}=\sin 45^{\circ}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Second angles $30^{\circ}$ and $60^{\circ}$. for these take an equilateral triangle and divide it down the middle, getting a $90^{\circ}/60^{\circ}/30^{\circ}$ triangle with sides $c=1$ and $a=\frac{1}{2}$ . Now Pythagoras gives $b=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and the trig functions can be read off the triangle. Finally all other angles follow just by understanding the unit circle.

Comment: +1. This isn't much of memorization; however, this is also how I obtain my results. This method is good for people who don't want to memorize and rather deduce when needed.

Comment: @SirJony Well your exactly right. Actually, I am opposed to all memorization schemes, they are not helpful nor contain insight. Better to deeply understand the subject. Unfortunately, university courses in the sciences emphasise extensive memorization.

Answer (score 2):

This might help, perhaps:
$$\sin^2 0= 0/4$$
$$\sin^2 \pi/6 = 1/4$$
$$\sin^2 \pi/4 = 2/4$$
$$\sin^2 \pi/3 = 3/4$$
$$\sin^2 \pi/2 = 4/4$$

Comment: Faving this question, wow, I get lots of ways to make my life easier <3

Comment: +1. This is the first time I've seen something memorizable regarding common angles! Not that I need to memorize, I just deduce them when I forget. :)

Answer (score 0):

I personally favour this method, as a visual thinker: [image: single theta] Basically, the vertical leg is the sine, the horizontal leg is the cosine, and you can use the picture below ...

[image: circle trig]

... to remember many different angles. But, like mentioned in the comments, there is nothing to beat practice in math.

Comment: I don't understand it :C

Comment: Ah, sorry. I think I may be able to find a better image, but basically I imagine the blue lines as hypotenuses to right triangles. In the 30 deg one for example, I think of a right triangle with legs of length sqrt(3)/2 on the X axis, and a leg going up with length 1/2. The hypotenuse itself is length 1, so $cos(30) = sqrt(3)/2$ and $sin(30) = 1/2$.

Comment: Cool :D But I need to copy this to my brain xD

Answer (score 0):

This is a very, very simple mnemonic which my mother taught me when I was 6. It was far easier to remember than the mnemonics they tried to teach us at school because it is one that you can reconstruct for yourself whenever you need it.

1. Draw a right-angled triangle.
2. Give letters to the angles. It is obvious that **A** and **B** should be the interesting angles, so label them like that. **C** is always exactly 90 degrees, which is boring. And you should always do the interesting things first and leave the boring ones until last: so that is easy to remember.
3. Give letters to the sides. How to do it? The most obvious way is to give the same letter to the side **opposite** each angle. So do that. Thus the diagonal is **c** and the other sides are **a** and **b**. Using opposite sides is **obvious** and therefore **memorable**.

You get a diagram like this:

[image]

And now comes the only bit of memorising you need to do:

- $\sin{A}=a/c$
- $\cos{A}=b/c$
- $\tan{A}=a/b$

This is easy to remember because sines and cosines are similar to each other and should therefore have the same denominator - which they do.

And the tangent is the only function with a different denominator. It is also the only function which you can make infinite, by making the side **b** smaller and smaller until it gets to $0$.